# Check if the user enabled private mac address iOS 14

Tags: swift, ios14

I want to check if the user turned on the private address settings on the iOS 14. Is there something to request the current status of this setting?

UPD. Since iOS14 Apple uses randomized MAC addresses, so the Wi-Fi router cannot identify the device [link](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211227). Unfortunately, my application cannot work if the user enables a private address. So by starting the application I want to know if the user enables private address, and force it to disable this setting or leave the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no API to get the MAC address of the device since [iOS7](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS7.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013162-SW34), I and searching in the docs, I couldn't find any information about the private address flag.
It seems to be a user settings, there might be some private API to get it, but nothing public.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Since iOS14 Apple uses randomized MAC addresses, so the Wi-Fi router cannot identify the device https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211227. I just wonder how can I force the user to off this setting.

Comment: I don't think it is possible

Comment: It seems you're right. But I'm still open to other answers